# Understanding the pointers in C

Tags: c, list, pointers

can someone actually give me some explanation how this part of the code works and what each pointer means.

```
void swapNode(node** A, node** B){
worker temp = (*(*A)).data;

(*A)->data = (*B)->data;
(*(*B)).data = temp;}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's full of unnecessary clutter. Can **you** explain what `worker` is?

Comment: No reason to use double pointers for this function.

Comment: @stark that's part of what I meant :)

Comment: Which book are you reading? This is a basic problem with which people who read decent books don't ask about; the book solves them. What you're asking us to do is reproduce entire chapters from various books, with this vague question which doesn't identify a precise point of confusion. **Read a book, quote confusing words from the book and ask about that when you have questions... DO NOT ask without first having researched (by reading a book)**.

Comment: I should also point out that it's generally dangerous to try to learn C without a decent guide (such as a good book). You risk learning a language that *seems* similar to C, but is subtly different in some devastating (and non-portable) ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass two pointer-to-pointer-to-node to the function:

```
void swapNode(node** A, node** B){
```

then you make a copy of the data of the node A (node.data)

```
worker temp = (*(*A)).data; //this is the same as (**A).data or (*A)->data and hopefully data is of the type worker...
```

Copy data from B to A

```
(*A)->data = (*B)->data;
```

And write the copy from the first step into the node where `**B` points to (the pointer that is stored at *B and *B is at the address stored in B).

A classic but very complicated swap.

```
(*(*B)).data = temp;
}
```

---

But generally it would be better to use only one level of pointers instead of two. Because there is no instance where you manipulate the first level of reference. You could just delete a `*` everywhere.

```
void swapNode(node* A, node* B)
{
  worker temp = A->data;
  A->data = B->data;  
  B->data = temp;
}
```

This is much easier to read and understand.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that `a->data` is shorthand for `(*a).data` where `a` is a pointer to a struct or union, and we need to *dereference* the pointer before we can access the `data` member.  Graphically:

```
   node *      node
   +---+       +---+
a: |   | ----> |   | 
   +---+       +---+
                ...
               +---+ 
               |   | data
               +---+
                ...
```

Thus, `(*(*A)).data` is equivalent to `(*A)->data`.

Based on the definition of `swapNode`, it looks like it would be called as follows:

```
node x, y;
...
node *xp = &x;
node *yp = &y;

swapNode( &xp, &yp );
```

Which makes sense if you're swapping the *pointer* values (setting `xp` to point to `y` and `yp` to point to `x`), but that's not what `swapNode` does; all it does is swap the `data` member between the two node instances.

For whatever reason, whoever wrote this code decided to add a completely unnecessary level of indirection.  It would work just as well if written

```
void swapNode(node* A, node* B)
{
  worker temp = A->data;

  A->data = B->data;
  B->data = temp;
}
```

and called as

```
node x, y;
...
swapNode( &x, &y );
```

Comment: I replaced what could be construed as a subtraction operator with "where". Do feel free to roll back if you don't like it.

Answer (score 0):

Here

`void swapNode(node** A, node** B)` A and B both are pointer of pointer type node.

`worker temp = (*(*A)).data;` here with first dereferencing `(*A)` we got the value of `A` which is a pointer of type `node` hence after the second dereferencing `(*(*A))` we got the value of `node` object so through the object we are retrieving the value stored in `data`.

Now in below code:-

`(*A)->data = (*B)->data;` with dereferencing we retrieve the address of A and B both are pointer to type `node` so with `->` we retrieved the data member of both and assigning the value of B's data to A.